# Closed form integral $\int_b^c \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(c-x)(d-x)}} dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Is there a closed form expression for the definite integral $$I=\int_b^c \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(c-x)(d-x)}} dx$$ for $a<b<c<d$?

Mathematica 9.0 can do it for special cases using elliptic integrals, so I suspect that there may be a more general closed form solution. Some examples:

For $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$, $d=4$:
$$I=-2 E\left(\frac34\right) - K\left( \frac34  \right) + 32 K\left( -3  \right) - 20\, \Pi(-1,-3)$$
For $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=3$, $d=5$:
$$I=-\sqrt{6}\, E\left(\frac23\right) - \sqrt{6}\, K\left( \frac34  \right) + 25\sqrt{2}\, K\left( -2  \right) - \frac{33}{\sqrt{2}}\, \Pi\left(-\frac12,-2\right)$$
For $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=5$, $d=7$:
$$I=-\sqrt{20}\, E\left(\frac9{10}\right) - \sqrt{5}\, K\left( \frac9{10}  \right) + 49\sqrt{2}\, K\left( -9  \right) - \frac{75}{\sqrt{2}}\, \Pi\left(-\frac32,-9\right)$$
For $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=7$, $d=11$:
$$I=-\sqrt{54}\, E\left(\frac{25}{27}\right) + \frac{103\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{27}}\, K\left( \frac{25}{27}  \right) - \frac{42\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{27}}\, \Pi\left(-\frac59,\frac{25}{27}\right)$$

Comment: There is an awful closed form expression for the antiderivative. For the integral, I did not arrive anywhere.

Comment: I have been able to compute the values of the antiderivative at $x=b$ and $x=c$, and the result is just a few miles long ! Good luck !

Comment: I wonder if we could not make things simpler writing $x^2 =(x-a)(x-b)+(a+b)(x-a)+a^2$ and work the three integrals separatly. What do you think ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks, that is very useful. Having found a closed form expression for the antiderivative means that the answer to the question is "Yes". I am not sure I understand why the antiderivative is a mile long. Where does the complexity come from? Surely it must be possible to simplify the expression, especially at the special points $b$ and $c$. I am not sure how you could turn the problem into thee integrals, as you suggest. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I do not know ! This is an idea which came to my mind; it makes the expression "simpler". I put in an answer the result when you replace $x^2$ of the numerator by $1$ (this corresponds to the third integral). Let me know your feeling.

Comment: I gave up since I have to go. I shall try tomorrow. Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $a < b < c < d$, let $I^{(n)}(a,b,c,d)$ and $J^{(n)}(a,d)$ be the integrals defined by:

$$
\begin{align}
I^{(n)}(a,b,c,d) &= \int_b^c \frac{x^n dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)}}\\
J^{(n)}(a,d)     &= I^{(n)}(a,-1,1,d)
\end{align}
$$
By a change of variable $x = \left(\frac{c-b}{2}\right)\left( u + \frac{c+b}{c-b}\right)$, it is easy to check

$$I^{(n)}(a,b,c,d) 
= \left(\frac{c-b}{2}\right)^{n-1}
\sum_{\ell=0}^n \binom{n}{\ell} J^{(n-\ell)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) 
\left(\frac{c+b}{c-b}\right)^\ell 
$$

where $\tilde{a} = \frac{2a - (b+c)}{c-b}$ and $\tilde{d} = \frac{2d-(b+c)}{c-b}$. To get an expression for the integral we want, i.e. that for $I^{(2)}(a,b,c,d)$, we just need to figure out what $J^{(\ell)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d})$ are for  $\ell = 0, 1, 2$.

Consider another change of variables

$$x = \frac{y+\lambda}{1+\lambda y} \quad\longleftrightarrow\quad y = \frac{x-\lambda}{1-\lambda x}$$
where $\lambda$ is a root of following equation with $|\lambda| \le 1$:

$$\frac{\tilde{a} - \lambda}{1 - \lambda \tilde{a}} 
+ \frac{\tilde{d} - \lambda}{1 - \lambda \tilde{d}} = 0
\quad\iff\quad
\lambda^2 - 2\left(\frac{\tilde{a}\tilde{d}+1}{\tilde{a}+\tilde{d}}\right)\lambda + 1 = 0
$$
For the parameter ranges relevant to this question, we have $\lambda = \frac{\Lambda}{1+\sqrt{1-\Lambda^2}}$ where $\Lambda = \frac{\tilde{a}+\tilde{d}}{1+\tilde{a}\tilde{d}}$.
Next, let $\;\displaystyle\mu = \frac{\tilde{d} - \lambda}{1 - \lambda \tilde{d}}\;$, 
we have
$$
\tilde{a} = \frac{-\mu + \lambda}{1 -\mu\lambda}\quad\text{ and }\quad
\tilde{d} = \frac{\mu  + \lambda}{1 +\mu\lambda}$$
It is easy to check

$$\begin{align}
x - 1 =& \frac{y + \lambda}{1+\lambda y}-1 = \frac{(y-1)(1-\lambda)}{1+\lambda y}\\
x + 1 =& \frac{y + \lambda}{1+\lambda y}+1 = \frac{(y+1)(1+\lambda)}{1+\lambda y}\\
x - \tilde{a} =& \frac{y + \lambda}{1+\lambda y}-\frac{-\mu + \lambda}{1 -\lambda\mu} 
= \frac{(y+\mu)(1-\lambda^2)}{(1+\lambda y)(1-\lambda\mu)}\\
x - \tilde{d} =& \frac{y + \lambda}{1+\lambda y}-\frac{\mu + \lambda}{1 + \lambda\mu}
= \frac{(y-\mu)(1-\lambda^2)}{(1+\lambda y)(1+\lambda\mu)}\\
\end{align}$$
Since $dx = \frac{(1-\lambda^2)dy}{(1+\lambda y)^2}$, we get

$$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-\tilde{a})(x^2-1)(x-\tilde{d})}} = 
\sqrt{\frac{1-\lambda^2\mu^2}{1-\lambda^2}}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{(1-y^2)(\mu^2-y^2)}}
$$

Let $k = \frac{1}{\mu}$,
$A(\lambda,\mu) = \frac{1}{\mu}\sqrt{\frac{1-\lambda^2\mu^2}{1-\lambda^2}} 
= \sqrt{\frac{k^2-\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}}$ and $P(y,k) = (1-y^2)(1-k^2y^2)$, 
we have

$$\begin{align}
J^{(0)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) = & 2A(\lambda,\mu)\int_0^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{P(y,k)}}\\
J^{(1)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) = & A(\lambda,\mu)\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{P(y,k)}}
\left[ \frac{ y+\lambda}{1+\lambda y}
      +\frac{-y+\lambda}{1-\lambda y} \right]\\
J^{(2)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) = & A(\lambda,\mu)\int_0^1\frac{dy}{\sqrt{P(y,k)}}
\left[ \left(\frac{ y+\lambda}{1+\lambda y}\right)^2
      +\left(\frac{-y+\lambda}{1-\lambda y}\right)^2 \right]\\
\end{align}$$

Let $\eta = \lambda^2$. In terms of following complete elliptic integrals,
\begin{align}
K(k) &= \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-k^2z^2)}}\\
E(k)  &= \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-k^2 z^2}{1-z^2}} dz\\
\Pi(\eta,k) &= \int_0^1 \frac{dz}{(1 - \eta z^2)\sqrt{(1-z^2)(1-k^2 z^2)}}
\end{align}

It is easy to see
$$J^{(0}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) = 2A(\lambda,\mu) K(k).$$

Notice

$$\frac{y+\lambda}{1+\lambda y} +\frac{-y+\lambda}{1-\lambda y}
= \frac{2\lambda(1-y^2)}{1-\lambda^2 y^2}
= \frac{2}{\lambda}\left[1 - \frac{1-\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2y^2}\right]$$
We get

$$J^{(1)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) = \frac{2A(\lambda,\mu)}{\lambda}(K(k) - (1-\eta)\Pi(\eta,k))$$

Similarly, we have
$$\left(\frac{ y+\lambda}{1+\lambda y}\right)^2
      +\left(\frac{-y+\lambda}{1-\lambda y}\right)^2
= \frac{2}{\lambda^2}\left\{
1 
- \frac{(1-\eta)(3-\eta)}{1-\eta y^2}
+ 2\frac{(1-\eta)^2}{(1-\eta y^2)^2}
\right\}\\
= \frac{2}{\lambda^2}\left\{
1 
- (1-\eta)\left[
(1+\eta)-2\eta(1-\eta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}
\right]
\frac{1}{1-\eta y^2}
\right\}
$$ 
Form this, we find

$$\begin{align}
J^{(2)}(\tilde{a},\tilde{d}) 
= &\frac{2A(\lambda,\mu)}{\lambda^2}\left[
K(k) - (1-\eta)\left( 1+\eta - 2\eta(1-\eta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}\right)\Pi(\eta,k)
\right]\\
= &
2A(\lambda,\mu)\left[
K(k) + \frac{1-\eta}{\eta-k^2}\left( E(k) - (1-k^2)\Pi(\eta,k) \right)
\right]
\end{align}$$

In the last expression, we have used following identity
$$
\frac{\partial\Pi(\eta,k)}{\partial \eta} = \frac{1}{2\eta(k^2 - \eta)(\eta-1)}\left(\eta E(k) + (k^2 -\eta)K(k) + (\eta^2 - k^2)\Pi(\eta,k)\right)
$$
to get rid of the derivatives of $\Pi(\eta,k)$.

Collect everything, we have

$$I^{(2)}(a,b,c,d) = (c-b)\sqrt{\frac{k^2-\lambda^2}{1-\lambda^2}}
\left\{
\begin{align}
 & K(k) \left(\frac{c+b}{c-b}\right)^2\\
+ & \frac{2}{\lambda}(K(k) - (1-\lambda^2)\Pi(\lambda^2,k)) \left(\frac{c+b}{c-b}\right)\\
+ & 
K(k) + \frac{1-\lambda^2}{\lambda^2-k^2}\left( E(k) - (1-k^2)\Pi(\lambda^2,k) \right)
\end{align}
\right\}
$$
Please note that in the case where $a+d = b+c$, $\tilde{a} + \tilde{d} = 0 \implies \lambda = 0$. Even though there is a term proportional to $\frac{2}{\lambda}$ in the second line of above expression, it won't cause any problem. 
This is because for small $\lambda$, $\Pi(\lambda^2,k) = K(k) + O(\lambda^2)$. That
part actually vanishes in the limit of small $\lambda$.

I suspect above expression can be further simplified but I haven't figure out a good way to do that yet.

Comment: All your answers are awesome!(+1)

Comment: @achille hui. This is splendid. Thanks for such a beautiful answer. Having seen this, I stop working this problem.

Comment: @achille hui. For my personal education, could you describe the paths you used for reaching a so beautiful result ? I tried four different CAS. They all gave up with the integral (the antiderivative was a mile - or lamost - long). Thanks and cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I can perform the integral because I know the answer will be in such a form before I start.  Before $20^{th}$ century, how to perform integral of the form $\int \frac{P(z)}{\sqrt{Q(z)}} dz$ where $P, Q$ are polynomials is a hot research topic. One main result is if $\deg Q = 3$ or $4$, definite integral between two roots of $Q(z)$ can be expressed in terms of 3 standard functions using Mobius transform. This is what we call the complete elliptic integrals today. In certain sense, elliptic integrals are created so that we can have an answer for this type of integrals.

Comment: Great answer! I would like to use your result in a paper I am writing in an astrophysics journal and would like to give credit to you in the acknowledgements. Could you tell me your name (or send it in email)?

Comment: @bkocsis, this is standard stuff in last century, no need to credit me.

Comment: OK, thanks anyways. "Last century" means the 19th?

Comment: I mean end of $19^{th}$ to the early $20^{th}$ century.

Comment: Did you check the singularities at $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = k$?

Comment: @bkocsis $\lambda = 1$ is never a issue. This is because
$$(1 + \tilde{a}\tilde{d})^2 - (\tilde{a}+\tilde{d})^2 = (\tilde{a}^2-1)(\tilde{d}^2-1) > 0 \implies |\Lambda| < 1 \implies |\lambda| < 1 $$
For the $|\lambda| = k$ case, first consider the subcase $\tilde{a}+\tilde{d} > 0 $, then $\lambda > 0$ and
$$|\lambda| = k \iff \lambda\mu = 1 \implies \frac{\tilde{a}-\lambda}{1-\tilde{a}\lambda}\lambda = -\mu\lambda = -1 \iff \frac{1-\lambda^2}{1-\tilde{a}\lambda} = 0$$
which is impossible. The subcase for $\tilde{a}+\tilde{d} < 0$ is similiar.

Comment: Oops, screwed up the sign of previous argument. $\lambda > 0$ corresponds to $\tilde{a}+\tilde{d} < 0$ instead of $> 0$ but the argument $\lambda\mu \ne \pm 1$ remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

This integral is listed in [Byrd and Friedman](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0)
\begin{equation}
I^{(2)}(a,b,c,d)=\frac{d^2}{\sqrt{(d-b)(c-a)}}\big\{2K(k)+4(b^2/a^2-1)\Pi(\alpha^2,k)+ 
\frac{\alpha^2E(k)+(k^2-\alpha^2)K(k) + (2\alpha^2k^2+2\alpha^2-\alpha^4-3k^2)\Pi(\alpha^2,k)}{(\alpha^2-1)(k^2-\alpha^2)}\bigg\}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha^2=(c-b)/(d-b)$, $k^2=\alpha^2(d-a)/(c-a)$.